On-screen keyboard popup on chromium text field input
I am running a web app on my pi using streamlit. I want my pi to operate as a standalone system so I have it connected to a touchscreen and I have a systemd script to autostart my streamlit app and the chromium browser in full-screen mode on boot-up.
I want a keyboard to pop-up when I interact with a text input field on the browser, and disappear when I click off the text input. I haven't found much info on this being possible. From what I've seen, you can have a permanent on-screen keyboard, or an interactive keyboard but not when in fullscreen and requires some manipulation of javascript backend.
Is there any compatible keyboard tool that can achieve what I want while also not being too complicated to integrate?
